# SWIFT の　実機テストにおけるエラー(libswiftCore.dylib)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

開発環境
Xcode7.2  Swift2.0　実機iPhone5s

コードが書けてきたので実機テストを行おうと思い実機をつなげてランしたところ、ビルドが完了した直後に以下のようなメッセージが出てデバッグが止まります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

様々なサイトを閲覧したところ、Certificate周りの問題ではないかと思い、
Certificateをrevokeし作り直し、それに伴いAppIDやprovisioningも作り直ししましたが全く変わらず。
また、設定の問題かもしれないということで
・Embedded Content Contains Swift Code をYesに
・Runpath Search Paths　に　＠executable_path/Frameworksを設定
などしましたが全く変わらずです。

どなたか少しでも解決につながるような案があったら教えていただきたく思います。